# Send and Extract zip file to azure VM using powershell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, rdp, winrm, azure-vm

I am trying to send and extract the zip file to azure VM but unable make the connection to the remote Azure VM.

**Code**

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$SO = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
$session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3389' -Credential $cred -SessionOption $SO

Send-File -Path C:\testArchive.zip -Destination C:\ -Session $session
Expand-Archive -Path C:\testArchive.zip -DestinationPath C:\ -Session $session
```

**Error**

```
New-PSSession : [xx.xx.xxx.xxx] Connecting to remote server xx.xx.xxx.xxx 
failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the 
destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the 
destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and 
documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most 
commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the 
following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM 
service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the 
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:4 char:12
+ $session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3389' - ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:Re 
   moteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

**Below is the output when i run 'winrm quickconfig' command on azure VM**

```
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

**When I run the 'Enter-PSSession -ComputerName LoadTestVm -Port 3389 -Credential qa-admin'**

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server LoadTestVm failed with the following error 
message : The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be 
resolved. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName LoadTestVm -Port 3389 -Credential qa-ad ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (LoadTestVm:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRem 
   otingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Comment: If you just do an `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName VMName` and enter the credentials when prompted does that work?  If no, you've found your problem.  If yes, then it is likely a problem with your `$cred` object.  Try `$cred = Get-Credential` and enter the username/password pair manually and feed that object to your `New-PSSession` and see if that works.

Comment: Updated the question with output. @Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WINRM will run on either ports 5985 and 5986. The port 5985 is for HTTP and 5986 is for HTTPS. By default, it uses port 5985 if you have not specified it with `-port`. You should specify port 5985 instead of 3389, also enable it in your NSG if you have.  So you could run `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "PublicIPaddress of VM" -Port 5985 -Credential $cred`.

This works on my side.

```
Copy-Item -Path D:\nancy\4.zip -Destination C:\ –ToSession $session

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Expand-Archive -Path C:\4.zip -DestinationPath C:\ }
```

More references:

https://www.assistanz.com/access-azure-windows-vm-through-powershell/

https://geekdudes.wordpress.com/2016/11/16/enabling-remote-powershell-connection-to-azure-virtual-machine/

https://mohitgoyal.co/2016/11/10/enable-powershell-remoting-on-azure-rm-virtual-machines/

Comment: Great now I am able to create session successfully. There is some issue in 'Send-File' and 'Expand-Archive'. Can you help in sending zip file and extract on vm.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a best practice risk management/Security-wise.

```
<#
$username = 'qa-admin'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'xxxxxxxx' -AsPlainText -Force
#>
```

This ...

```
<#
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
#>
```

... there is a built-in cmdlet for this.

Never pass clear text passwords in a script. Either:

1. prompt for them
2. Read them from a secure pre-created file

> [Quickly and securely storing your credentials – PowerShell](https://www.jaapbrasser.com/quickly-and-securely-storing-your-credentials-powershell)
>
> [Working with Passwords, Secure Strings and Credentials in Windows
>   PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx)

3. from Windows credential manager

> [CredentialManager 2.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager/2.0)
>
> [Accessing Windows Credentials Manager from PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Accessing-Windows-7210ae91)
>
> [How to Manage Secrets and Passwords with CredentialManager and
>   PowerShell](https://www.scriptinglibrary.com/languages/powershell/how-to-manage-secrets-and-passwords-with-credentialmanager-and-powershell/)

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential $env:USERNAME
```

This...

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3389' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

...is not correct. You cannot do this. You need the results of the above to pass to the -SessionOption param.

```
Get-Help -Name New-PSSessionOption -Examples

<#
NAME
    New-PSSessionOption

SYNOPSIS
    Creates an object that contains advanced options for a PSSession.


Example 1: Create a default session option

    PS C:\>New-PSSessionOption
...

This command creates a session option object that has all of the default values.
Example 2: Configure a session by using a session option object

    PS C:\>$pso = New-PSSessionOption -Culture "fr-fr" -MaximumReceivedObjectSize 10MB
    PS C:\>New-PSSession -ComputerName Server01 -SessionOption $pso

...

Example 3: Start an interactive session

    PS C:\>Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server01 -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -NoEncryption -NoCompression)

...
Example 4: Modify a session option object

    PS C:\>$a = New-PSSessionOption
...

PS C:\> $a.UICulture = (Get-UICulture)
PS C:\> $a.OpenTimeout = (New-Timespan -Minutes 4)
PS C:\> $a.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 1
PS C:\> $a

...

Example 5: Create a preference variable

    PS C:\>$PSSessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -OpenTimeOut 120000

...

Example 6: Fulfill the requirements for a remote session configuration

    PS C:\>$skipCN = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCNCheck
    PS C:\>New-PSSession -ComputerName 171.09.21.207 -UseSSL -Credential Domain01\User01 -SessionOption $SkipCN

...

Example 7: Make arguments available to a remote session

    PS C:\>$team = @{Team="IT"; Use="Testing"}
    PS C:\>$TeamOption = New-PSSessionOption -ApplicationArguments $team
    PS C:\>$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server01 -SessionOption $TeamOption
    PS C:\>Invoke-Command -Session $s {$PSSenderInfo.SpplicationArguments}

...

    PS C:\>Invoke-Command -Session $s {if ($PSSenderInfo.ApplicationArguments.Use -ne "Testing") {.\logFiles.ps1} else {"Just testing."}}
...
#>
```

So, yours is...

```
$SO       = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
$session  = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3389' -Credential $cred -SessionOption $SO

# Process other actions
Send-File -Path C:\testArchive.zip -Destination C:\ -Session $session
Expand-Archive -Path C:\testArchive.zip -DestinationPath C:\ -Session $session
```

Comment: thanks. ok, forget about passing the parameter through the script. Still, the error is the same when I provide the credential at runtime. I updated the question.

Comment: If you are passing a cred to a domain-joined resource needs to be in DomainName\Username and password, not just username and password. If you are going cross-domain, cross-forest, then you have a Windows double-hop auth problem. There are docs on how to address that as well. If this is a workgroup, then more setup is required on both the host and destination.